# onclick button multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I use the function onclick to change my buttons background color but I want them to get back to the normal color when I click a second time on it.

Here's the HTML code :

```
<div class="price">
                <label for="price">My donation: </label>
                <button class="fifty_button" onclick="changeColor(fifty)" ondblclick="">$50</button>
                <button class="hundred_button" onclick="changeColor(hundred)">$100</button>
                <button class="twohundred_button" onclick="changeColor(twohundred)">$250</button>
                <button class="fivehundred_button" onclick="changeColor(fivehundred)">$500</button>
            </div>
```

and here's my JS code :

```
function changeColor(fifty, hundred, twohundred, fivehundred){
    fifty.style.background = "red";
    hundred.style.background="red";
    twohundred.style.background="red";
    fivehundred.style.background="red";
}
```

I tried to create another function but it just disables the first one.

Comment: I would rather suggest you to play with CSS. Create a default CSS with, say, `.redcls {background:red;}`  another class say, `.bluecls {background:blue;}` and then add bluecls if does not exists in list, remove otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your changeColor function has 4 params and you are passing only one ?

Also you are not accessing element by its id.

Here is the full working example

```html
<div class="price">
                <label for="price">My donation: </label>
                <button class="fifty_button" onclick="changeColor(this)" ondblclick="">$50</button>
                <button class="hundred_button" onclick="changeColor(this)">$100</button>
                <button class="twohundred_button" onclick="changeColor(this)">$250</button>
                <button class="fivehundred_button" onclick="changeColor(this)">$500</button>
            </div>
  <script>
  function changeColor(element) {
 
  if (element.style.background == 'red') {
         element.style.background = null;
  } else {
        element.style.background = "red"; 
    }
}</script>
```